# how to get bug count from every file of the project in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

if anybody knows please give me sql query or idea, I am not able to find common thing for getting bug count from projects_measures and projects table.

Comment: You'll need to give more details and precision to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this curl request:

```
curl <SONARQUBE_URL>/api/issues/search?ps=1&projectKey=<PROJECT_KEY>&facets=types
```

by using facets=types you will get the number of issues by type (bugs, code smells and vulnerabilities).

Comment: Hello Begarco,

I have two project , even if I mentioned diff project key in my api query it still prints the same value, can you help me how to filter it out project specific, i tried to remove ps from as well but no luck curl  -u admin:XXXXXXX -X GET 'https://mysqserver.com/sonarqube/api/issues/search?ps=1&projectKey=reactjs-demo&facets=types'  , one project has 3 bugs and other has 34 bugs but it always prints 34 bugs for both project , can you guide

Comment: What is the version of your SonarQube instance ?

Comment: Hello Begarco, 
I have figured it out, I will using wrong parameters :)